# Php + Microsoft analysis service (OLAP cube) - PHP БД/MS SQL

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-server, ssas

Нужна помощь,литература,проекты готовые как пример, код можно. Короче как можно работать с Analysis Services на PHP. Примеры что угодно, гугл не сильно помог, поэтому объясните как с этим работать от подключения до простых-сложных запросов, как примеры. Буду благодарен.Платформа которая используется для разработки Wordpress. И другие базы данных или платформы не интересуют, по причине постановки задачи начальником. Сделать использую платформу wordpress and Microsoft SQL Server. OLAp-cube сделать на Microsoft Analysis Service

Comment: Мне нужна для ознакомления литература, сайты, готовые проекты, примеры кода подключения и простых запросов на тему как можно работать с Microsoft Analysis Services на php. В интернете я этого не нашел

Comment: Здравствуйте,неужели никто не знает, как можно работать с php+Microsoft Analysis service

Comment: может стоит начать с этого http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: там есть очень полезный комментарий, если нужен перевод - сообщите в ответном комментарии: For those trying to connect PHP 5.2 to a 2005 Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) cube and execute MDX queries, you have to establish a link via a trusted connection from the Database Service to SSAS using a stored procedure, then execute the stored procedure via PHP